In a single select, use a selected column result also in a MySQL function?
as an idea example this here kind of thing
Select salt2, SHA2('A11111111111111111111' + 'salt2', 512) from usertable;
Where the salt value in salt2 column will be used in the sha2 function.
The hash to be made is from the string "A11111111111111111111" plus the string value in salt2 column. As in appended onto the end.
So, use the value in salt2 column, in the function, all in one select statement
For trying of course tried what I wrote, but it's a concept not working code yet.
If this cannot be done, I can try nested readers. As in gather the salt, in one select, then run a separate select in a nested reader to generate the hash.
I am comparing my stored hash in 'priv_aes' column with this generated hash from above here to see if any user has all privileges for use in my vbnet program. This is not a mysql user table with grants, it is my own user table.
Table explained, last 3 columns have hashed values.
MariaDB [booksgood]> explain usertable
    -> ;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| MyName       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     |                     |                |
| Myuser       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     |                     |                |
| password     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     |                     |                |
| Priveliges   | char(21)     | YES  |     |                     |                |
| TS           | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| UserDate     | datetime     | YES  |     | current_timestamp() |                |
| password_aes | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| priv_aes     | varchar(150) | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| salt2        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.034 sec)

MariaDB [booksgood]>


String concatenation in MySQL

And of course you need to concatenate with the column, and not a text literal.

Also there should be a separator between the salt and text that isn't common to both. If using 11.4 lts there is KDF for this sort of thing.

Maybe , just maybe I got it, thanks

MariaDB [booksgood]> select sha2(concat('A11111111111111111111',salt2), 512) as "Name" from usertable; seems to report a matching hash.

Thanks for the help! I dont see a way to mark solved, but it is solved, and I can collect multiple columns too like doing this   MariaDB [booksgood]> select sha2(concat('A11111111111111111111',salt2), 512) as "Name", salt2, myuser from usertable;

If no answer is posted you can simply delete the question.

The following code works nicely:
select sha2(concat('A11111111111111111111',salt2), 512) as "Name", salt2, myuser 
from usertable;

I also decided to create the hashes on the client, not the server, but I know how to do both now. Seems like everyone has an opinion on using server or client created hashes.
